# azure batch starttask giving error

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I am trying to create a `azure batch service`. While creating a `pool`, i am trying to give a starttask which should be run when the VM's are spinned up for the first time. After the pool is committed when i try to observe the progress on the Azure portal, state of the nodes appear as starttaskfailed. I could see the scheduling error inside the starttaskinfo. Error info is as given below.

```
CATEGORY - ServerError
CODE - BlobDownloadMiscError
MESSAGE - Miscellaneous error encountered while downloading one of the specified azure blob's.
```

Here I am trying to run the simple executable as a start task which is creating a container and writing a `blob`.
I have already tried to run the `exe` standalone from my machine, it performs the operation as expected.

But when I am trying to run the same thing as a start task, I am getting the aforementioned error.

P.S. I have already verified that all the paths and the required dependable(dll) are uploaded on to the blob.

Please help me in identifying the root cause of the problem. Even if i get to know the descriptive error message that would be of great help.

Comment: 1. please edit your question and remove tag [tag:batch-file] as it does not apply here; 2. if you have found the solution by yourself, you should provide an answer and delete the comment;

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this issue now. I had provided wrong container name so was getting this error as it was not able to locate the files in the given location. But while running a starttask it was not giving me any meaningful error neither in portal nor in code where it doesn't even give error. So as rectify this issue i tried running this as job and added this in its task where it correctly notified the error in ExecutionInformation->schedulingerror property of cloudtask.